# Converting a list of string to list of integer

Tags: python, list

So I have a list of string `a = ['1', '2', '']` or `a = ['1', '2', 'NAN']`, and I want to convert it to `[1, 2, 0]` or `[1, 2, -1]` (namely `NAN` to `-1`); I used
`a = [int(ele) for ele in a]`, but got an error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

So the empty string cannot be converted automatically. Of course I could explicitly loop through the list ,but I wonder if there are more elegant/compact/efficient way.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
>> a = ['1', '2', '']
>>> def toint(s, default=0):
...     try:
...         return int(s)
...     except ValueError:
...         return default
...
>>> [toint(x) for x in a]
[1, 2, 0]
>>>
```

This has the added benefit of conforming to Python's [Duck Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) idiom and giving you the flexibility to change the default if processing your data results in a `ValueError` exception. e.g:

```
>>> [toint(x, None) for x in a]
[1, 2, None]
```

Comment: But `''` should map to `0`

Comment: Really? Try ``int("")`` on the Python shell.

Comment: The test case `['1', '2', '']` is supposed to map to `[1, 2, 0]`

Comment: @gnibbler Don't nit pick. The provided solution above is flexible enough to take a different user provided default keyword argument.

Comment: Not nit picking at all. The question clearly maps `''` to `0` and `'NAN'` to `-1`. This answer is plain wrong.

Comment: Must we do all the work? It's **really** trivial to adapt the function to produce the *required* values.

Answer (score 1):

You could just write a function that makes use of `int` and then have a fallback condition on failures that does what you want for a input string, then call that function in the list comprehension statement.

example:

```
def converter(ele):
    # result = your integer conversion logic
    return result

a = [converter(ele) for ele in elements]
```

Comment: Thanks for the general idea, and I'll extend @JamesMills 's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your list comprehension a little as:

```
a = [int(ele) if ele else 0 for ele in a]
```

gives what you want. This will work if the non number is a '' not if it is a NAN. If 'NAN' is part of the list, this will do it:

```
a = [int(ele) if ele != 'NAN' else 0 for ele in a]
```

Comment: I think you mean to say `ele != 'NAN'`

Comment: `a = [int(ele) if ele not in 'NAN' else 0 for ele in a]` on `a = ['1', '2', 'NAN']` gives `[1, 2, 0]`.

Comment: It gives the right result by accident, but the semantics are wrong. 'N', 'A', 'NA', 'AN' should cause exception, but this is masked by using `in`

Comment: I used it since it was going to be 'NAN' or '' as the question said. Updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `dict` to handle your unusual values

```
a = [int({'NAN': '-1', '': 0}.get(i, i)) for i in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = ['1', '2', '', 'NAN']

>>> listofInt =  map(lambda s: int(s) if s not in 'NAN' else  -1 if s == 'NAN' else 0, a)

>>> print listofInt

>>> [1, 2, 0, -1]
```

You could write a lambda function even as a anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = ['1', '2', 'NAN', '']
>>> 
>>> def to_int(value):
...     try:
...         return int(value)
...     except ValueError:
...         if value == 'NAN':
...             return -1
...         return 0
... 
>>> [to_int(x) for x in a]
[1, 2, -1, 0]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def convert(myList):
    newList = [0]*len(myList)
    for i in range(len(myList)):
        try:
            newList[i] = int(myList[i])
        except:
            newList[i] = -1
    return newList
```

obviously this try/except just puts -1 for anything that can't be converted to an integer

easily converted to a more specific *if myList[i]=='NAN': newList[i]=-1*